# pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks

Tags: debian, apt

I am trying to run an `apt-get dist-upgrade`, but it comes with the following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Failed
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.14.2-21+deb7u2) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: perl-modules (>= 5.14.2-21+deb7u2) but it is not going to be installed
 sysvinit : PreDepends: initscripts (>= 2.88dsf-13.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I successfully ran `apt-get upgrade`, so I am out of ideas

I was thinking of `apt-get remove perl`, but then it comes with this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mount : PreDepends: libblkid1 (>= 2.20.1) but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libmount1 (>= 2.20.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

My `sources.list` looks like this

```
deb http://ftp.dk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.dk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security wheezy/updates main

deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports squeeze-backports main

deb http://mirrors.sunsite.dk/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://mirrors.sunsite.dk/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://ftp.ie.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.ie.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main non-free
```

What can I do?

The answers to the questions in comments are

The output of `cat /etc/debian_version` is `7.9`, but no I am not using `apt pinning` as your comment is the first place, I read about it, but I am going for setting it up, when `apt` is running

The output of `apt-cache policy` is

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/non-free i386 Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security,c=non-free
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/non-free Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/non-free i386 Packages
     release v=7.9,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=non-free
     origin ftp.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
     release v=7.9,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=jessie,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.ie.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.ie.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
     release v=7.9,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.ie.debian.org
 500 http://mirrors.sunsite.dk/debian/ wheezy/main Translation-en
 500 http://mirrors.sunsite.dk/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
     release v=7.9,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=main
     origin mirrors.sunsite.dk
 500 http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports/ squeeze-backports/main Translation-en
 100 http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports/ squeeze-backports/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=squeeze-backports,n=squeeze-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main
     origin backports.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security/ wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=7.0,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=wheezy,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates/main i386 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=testing,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=main
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.dk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main Translation-en
 500 http://ftp.dk.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
     release v=7.9,o=Debian,a=oldstable,n=wheezy,l=Debian,c=main
     origin ftp.dk.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```